# Mongoose, right way for create random string on a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create an model for my project and Im new for JS.

I want to generate a randomly string between 6 and 10 digits for my key value.

```
const objectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
userId : {type: String, required: true},
randomGeneratedString: ???
});
```

How can I do this with right way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `default` value from Schema to generate a random value.

```js
const objectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
userId : {type: String, required: true},
randomGeneratedString: {
    type: String,
    default: generateRandom = () => {
      // Here your function to generate random string
      return "yourRandomString"
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use mongoose midleware to implement schema that you want it
use code below to define your schema

```
 const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  randomGeneratedString: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 6,
    maxlength: 10,
  },
});

schema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  const randomInteger = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };
  this.randomGeneratedString = Math.random()
    .toString(36)
    .substr(2, randomInteger(6, 10));
  next();
});
```